# User data remain after logout in angular , nu clue why

Tags: angular, typescript, session

Everything works well, but when I want to switch an user and logout , the next user doesnt update its data , but inherits the last user images and data...
I use session storage and local storage , but even after the user gets removed from storage it still keep showing lol

This is my particular code:

**page1.ts**

```
  //vars
  personSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  person$: Observable<any> = this.personSubject.asObservable();
  getFullPosts: Observable<any>;
  public userGallery: any;

    getFullPosts() {
    this.authService.getAllPosts().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.getFullPosts = res.data.post;
      this.personSubject.next(res.data.post)
      this.userGallery = res.data.post.forEach(img => {
        img.galleryImages = img.images.map(image => {
          return new ImageItem({ src: image, thumb: image });
        });
      })
    });
```

**auth-service.ts**

```
//vars

constructor(){
 this.keepToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');

    if (this.completeUser != null) {
      console.log("User data is : ", this.getUser);
      console.log("User token is : ", this.keepToken);
    } else {
      console.log("Can't get token..")
    }
}

  public get getToken(): any {
    const TOKEN = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    return TOKEN;
  }

  public get getUser(): UserRegistered {
    const USER = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    return USER;
  }
```

**page2.ts**

```
 async logout() {
    // remove user from local storage and set current user to null
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('button', 'true');
    this.clicked = window.sessionStorage.getItem('button');

    const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      keyboardClose: true,
      message: "Logging out. Please wait ...",
      duration: 2500
    });

    (await loading).present();

    setTimeout(async () => {
      const user = window.sessionStorage.removeItem('user');
      const remember = window.sessionStorage.removeItem('remember');

      const getuser = window.sessionStorage.getItem('user');
      console.log(user, remember, getuser);

      window.sessionStorage.setItem('button', 'false');
      this.clicked = window.sessionStorage.getItem('button');
      const redirect = this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
      (await loading).dismiss();
      await redirect;
      window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }, 3500)

  }
```

After logout i relogin with another account , but data is not updated with the new user , but in console i get the new user data correct , only in the frontend doesnt show up. Any ideas?

Comment: In your setTimeout what your console.log print ? user data or undefined ? Otherwise why do you use ReplaySubject for your "person" ( it represent your user, right ?) because ReplaySubject can litteraly 'replay' old values, like your previous user

Comment: Would running `window.sessionStorage.clear();` ahead of redirecting work? Better yet, could you do it after the navigation has concluded?: `this.router.navigate(['/auth']).then(() => { window.sessionStorage.clear(); });`

Comment: @KevinALBRECHT  console.log(user, remember, getuser); after logout it gets me all values NULL. Didn't know that will repeat the call on replaysubject , what should I do instead?

Comment: @Inst1nct try with a simple "Subject" just to see if there is any changes 
More infos about types of subjects here : https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by removing the `localStorage` entry for "firebase:session::".

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("firebase:session::<host-name>");
```

Comment: Yo bro it works like a charm.. Idk what trick is this but as long as it works.. gg